# Парсинг xml из директории

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Есть задача парсить xml из папки, куда они заливаются раз в час, и записывать все в БД.

Как можно реализовать, так чтобы парсились все файлы в папке, причем в дальнейшем не нужно парсить те, которые уже прочитаны, т.е. только вновь появившиеся. Файлы из папки не удаляются, просто складываются туда.

Comment: Все просто, нужно отмечать, какие файлы уже распарсились. А по крону запускать скрипт для парсинга каждый час.

Comment: А можно поподробнее? )

Comment:     итерировать файлы через файл:
      если файл.время_модификации < время.текущее - час следовательно
        парсить файл.данные

Comment: Можно перед парсингом проверять, был ли файл уже обработан. Тем более, что в бд может быть полезной информация, что откуда пришло.

Comment: Если не трудно, напишите пример кода. Я головой-то примерно понимаю, но с реализацией проблема )